# Problem retrieving Google Analytics Tracker Name using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I use Google Tag Manager to implement Google Analytics. Thus, the tracker names initiated on my site are not always the same eg. gtm2, gtm3.

The overall objective is to be able to send data to my custom metric as follows:

`ga( 'gtm2.set', 'metric2', 'custom metric data');`

I can't figure out why this code would not work:

```
var yone = (ga.getAll()[1].get("name"));
var ytwo = ".set";
var ythree = yone.concat(ytwo);
ga( ythree, 'metric2', 'custom metric data');
```

The error in Javascript console is that "VM3324:1 Uncaught TypeError: ga.getAll is not a function". I am not sure why this is showing since when I do `console.log(ga.getAll()[1].get("name"));`, the correct tracker name shows up in console log ie. gtm2.

**EDIT**
I tried out introducing the callback function as mentioned by @balexandre so my code became this:

```
var yone = ga(function() {
ga.getAll()[1].get("name")});
var ytwo = ".set";
var ythree = yone.concat(ytwo);
ga( ythree, 'metric2', 'custom metric data');
```

In this instance, console now shows a different error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined".

Thanks.

Comment: that only means, by the time you are executing your code, the GA library is not yet loaded... just pass a callback and you will be sure that your code will only be executed after the library is fully loaded... [more here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ga-object-methods-reference)

Comment: @balexandre Thanks. I tried out using the callback but get a different error message coming back this time? "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined". I have edited the main question to show the code I used. Thanks!

Comment: why don't you write `debugger;` and debug the code from there, and see what are you doing wrong? and BTW, look at your code ... you need to put everything inside the function, you don't know when the function fires ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a callback, so, you can't just call your code and hope all will work, it will not!

you tried this

```js
var yone = ga(function() {
  ga.getAll()[1].get("name")
});

var ytwo = ".set";
var ythree = yone.concat(ytwo);
ga( ythree, 'metric2', 'custom metric data');
```

but when you're in line `var ytwo` you don't have anything in `yone` yet, the call not yet fired... hence it's a callback (will only execute the code when the script is loaded), you don't know if it takes 1ms or 10 sec...

so, you should try:

```js
ga(function() {
  // debugger;
  var yone = ga.getAll()[1].get("name");
  var ytwo = ".set";
  var ythree = yone.concat(ytwo);
  ga( ythree, 'metric2', 'custom metric data');
});
```

and if you want, remove the comment and use the browser debugger to check all existing variables and execute the code, inside the callback...

Comment: This worked! Many thanks for not only providing a solution but for clearly explaining it :) Have a great weekend Sir!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with index 0 instead 1? Like this:

```
ga.getAll()[0].get("name");
```

The result if you not use GTM could be *t0*, with GTM could be *gtm**xx***.